# Docker-compose on Windows 10: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: docker-compose

When trying to run docker-compose,e.g.:
    docker-compose --version

the following error message appears:
    Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘encodings’

Current thread 0x0000228c (most recent call first):

Any suggestions how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: it might be helpful to know what platform you are running your docker container on.

Comment: Windows 10
===========
d:\>docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false